# Trouble swapping nodes in doubly linked list

Tags: c, list, data-structures, linked-list, swap

I am trying to swap two nodes in a doubly linked list using C. It is working if I pass in some values, for example the head and tail of the list, and some in between. However, on others the value of one seems to be overwritten by the other and I am thrown into a loop.

Node/List:

```
struct node //node for linked list
{
    unsigned long int *id;
    char *firstname, *lastname, *department;
    float *gpa;
    struct node *next, *prev;
};
struct linked_list //doubly linked_list data structure
{
    struct node *head, *tail;
};
```

I can successfully add nodes to the list and move the tail to the newly added node.

```
void *add_node(struct node **tail, unsigned long int *id, char *first, char *last, char *dept, float *gpa) //create a node, add to tail
{
    struct node *newStudent = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newStudent->firstname = (char*)malloc(strlen(first)+1);
    newStudent->lastname = (char*)malloc(strlen(last)+1);
    newStudent->department = (char*)malloc(strlen(dept)+1);
    newStudent->id = (unsigned long int*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned long int));
    newStudent->gpa = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float));

    *(newStudent->id) = *id;
    *(newStudent->gpa) = *gpa;

    strcpy(newStudent->firstname, first);
    strcpy(newStudent->lastname, last);
    strcpy(newStudent->department, dept);

    newStudent->next = NULL;
    if(tail) //not the first node in the list
    {
        newStudent->prev = *tail;
        (*tail)->next = newStudent;
        *tail = newStudent;
    }
    else //head of the list
        return newStudent;
}
```

And finally, my swap function:

```
void *_swap(struct node **x, struct node **y, struct linked_list **list)
{
    struct node *temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    memcpy(temp, *x, sizeof(struct node));

    if( (*y)->prev ) /// if y has a previous...
    {
        (*x)->prev = (*y)->prev;
        (*y)->prev->next = *x;
    }
    else
        (*x)->prev = NULL;

    if( (*y)->next )  /// if y has a next...
    {
        (*x)->next = (*y)->next;
        (*y)->next->prev = *x;
    }
    else
        (*x)->next = NULL;

    if( temp->prev) /// if original x has a previous...
    {
        (*y)->prev = temp->prev;
        temp->prev->next = *y;
    }
    else
        (*y)->prev = NULL;

    if(temp->next) /// if original x has a next...
    {
        (*y)->next = temp->next;
        temp->next->prev = *y;
    }
    else
    (*y)->next = NULL;

    free(temp);

    if((*list)->head == *x && (*list)->tail == *y)
    {
        (*list)->head = *y;
        (*list)->tail=*x;
    }
    else if((*list)->head == *y && (*list)->tail == *x)
    {
        (*list)->head = *x;
        (*list)->tail=*y;
    }
    else if((*list)->head == *x)
        (*list)->head = *y;
    else if((*list)->head == *y)
        (*list)->head = *x;
    else if((*list)->tail == *x)
        (*list)->tail = *y;
    else if((*list)->tail == *y)
        (*list)->tail = *x;

    printf("%s %s %s %s %s\n\n\n\n", (*list)->head->firstname, (*list)->head->next->firstname, (*list)->head->next->next->firstname, (*list)->head->next->next->next->firstname, (*list)->head->next->next->next->next->firstname);
}
```

When I call something like 
            temp->next->prev = *y;
it sometimes seems to overwrite the value of, in this case, x, instead of simply reassigning the linked_list pointer to y.

I am able to build my list just fine:

```
struct linked_list *list = (struct linked_list*)malloc(sizeof(struct linked_list));
list->head = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
list->tail = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
unsigned long int *id = malloc(sizeof(unsigned long int));
*id = 343232;
float gpa = 3.2;
list->head = add_node(NULL, id, "Matthew", "D", "CECS", &gpa);
list->tail = list->head;

add_node(&(list->tail), id, "John", "X", "PNY", &gpa);
add_node(&(list->tail), id, "Rebecca", "H", "ECE", &gpa);
```

Comment: Didn't read the code, so just guessing that you have the same problem as in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368233/is-anything-wrong-with-my-doubly-linked-list-swap-function/22368350#22368350)

Comment: A swap node function, should not be allocating a node. It should just change the previous and next pointers of the affected nodes, along with the list head and tail pointers if needed. To perform a minimal swap, normally you use a temp variable:  temp = a; a = b; b = temp; . In this case the temp variable would be a pointer to node. You need to perform the swap operations in a specific order in case the nodes are adjacent (the operation is more like a rotate rather than a swap).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of things that jump out in your code.

- You allocate a lot of stuff, often needlessly and uselessly. As rcgldr pointed out, the swap function should not allocate a new node. After all, the list consists of the same nodes, only in a different order, after swapping. There are no new nodes.
- Your "client code", i.e. the function that uses the linked-list functions, which is probably `main` in your example, shouldn't explicitly allocate memory. Neither should it populate the nodes by hand. It should just call `add_node` and `delete_node`, which you should also code in order to free all the allocated memory.
- There is no need to pass pointers to pointers in your case. It is enough to pass a pointer to the nodes and list struct. That allows you to alter the fields of the structs. A pointer to pointer to struct would only make sense if you wanted to alter the struct handle itself, for example by re-allocating it, but you don't do that. (Pointer to pointers are often used for singly-linked lists, where the head isn't stored in a struct. Even there, it might be useful to wrap the single pointer in a struct, so that there is no need for pointers to pointers.)
- All logic should happen inside your functions. Don't modify the `next` and `prev` pointers in ´main`; that's what the functions are for. When you call a function and when you return from it, certain "invariants" should hold true, for example:

  - When the list is empty, both `head` and `tail` are `NULL`.
  - Otherwise, the `head` points to the first node; ´head->prev`is`NULL`. The`tail`points to the last node; ´tail->next` is `NULL`.
  - When a node `nd` has a previous node, then `nd->prev->next == nd`.
  - Likewise, when a node `nd` has a next node, then `nd->next->prev == nd`.

  You can even write a sanity-check function to enforce these invarants on function entry and exit.
- You allocate data for all fields. Memory allocation makes sense for the strings, which are arrays of chars whose length you don't know beforehand. It doesn't make sense for the scalar variables `id` and `gpa`. You can declare them as non-pointers and just assign to them. (It is not wrong to allocate memory and access them via pointer, but direct access is much simpler.)
- Some of your functions return `void *`, the void pointer. That's not what you want. Either your functions should be `void` i.e without return value or they should return pointers to nodes. (The void pointer is a legal data type and refers to a pointer to any data type, which you can't dereference. It is used in generic functions such as `qsort` and should not be used in your code. You are not writing generic functions, but functions for your concrete linked list.)

You can look at a swap as removing the nodes and re-inserting them after their respective old predecessors. You still have to take care to catch the case where the nodes are adjacent.

Here's an example implementation that tries to respect the points I've mentioned above:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef unsigned long int ulong;

struct node
{
    ulong id;
    char *name;
    float gpa;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
};

struct list
{
    struct node *head;
    struct node *tail;
};



/*
 *      Create a new, unconnected node
 */
struct node *node_new(ulong id, const char *name, float gpa)
{
    struct node *node = malloc(sizeof(*node));  // Error checking!

    node->prev = NULL;
    node->next = NULL;
    node->id = id;
    node->gpa = gpa;

    node->name = malloc(strlen(name) + 1);
    strcpy(node->name, name);

    return node;
}

/*
 *      Create a list
 */
struct list *list_new()
{
    struct list *list = malloc(sizeof(*list));  // Error checking!

    list->head = list->tail = NULL;
    return list;
}

/*
 *      Add a student to list
 */
struct node *list_add(struct list *list,
    ulong id, const char *name, float gpa)
{
    struct node *node = node_new(id, name, gpa);

    node->prev = list->tail;
    if (list->tail == NULL) {
        list->head = list->tail = node;
    } else {
        list->tail->next = node;
        list->tail = node;
    }

    return node;
}

/*
 *      Delete a node from the list.
 */
void list_delete(struct list *list, struct node *node)
{
    if (node->prev) node->prev->next = node->next;
    else list->head = node->next;

    if (node->next) node->next->prev = node->prev;
    else list->tail = node->prev;

    free(node->name);
    free(node);
}

/*
 *      Find student by id; return NULL if not found.
 */
struct node *list_find_by_id(const struct list *list, ulong id)
{
    struct node *node = list->head;

    while (node) {
        if (node->id == id) return node;
        node = node->next;
    }

    return NULL;
}

/*
 *      Extract a node without deleting
 */
void list_remove(struct list *list, struct node *node)
{
    if (node->prev) node->prev->next = node->next;
    else list->head = node->next;

    if (node->next) node->next->prev = node->prev;
    else list->tail = node->prev;

    node->prev = node->next = NULL;
}

/*
 *      Insert node after prev or at the front when prev is NULL
 */
void list_insert_after(struct list *list,
    struct node *node, struct node *prev)
{
    if (prev) {
        node->next = prev->next;
        prev->next = node;
    } else {
        node->next = list->head;
        list->head = node;
    }
    node->prev = prev;
    if (node->next) node->next->prev = node;
}

/*
 *      Swap two nodes' positions in the list
 */
void list_swap(struct list *list, struct node *x, struct node *y)
{
    if (x == y) return;

    struct node *xprev = x->prev;
    struct node *yprev = y->prev;

    if (xprev == y) {            
        list_remove(list, x);
        list_insert_after(list, x, yprev);
    } else if (yprev == x) {            
        list_remove(list, y);
        list_insert_after(list, y, xprev);
    } else {
        list_remove(list, x);
        list_remove(list, y);

        list_insert_after(list, x, yprev);
        list_insert_after(list, y, xprev);
    }
}

/*
 *      Print list
 */
void list_print(const struct list *list)
{
    const struct node *node = list->head;

    while (node) {
        printf("%8lu  %-20s  %8.1f\n", node->id, node->name, node->gpa);
        node = node->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

/*
 *      Delete a list and all its nodes
 */
void list_destroy(struct list *list)
{
    while (list->head) list_delete(list, list->head);
    free(list);
}

/*
 *      Example client code using the list
 */
int main()
{
    struct list *list = list_new();

    list_add(list, 342232, "Matthew",   3.2);
    list_add(list, 342856, "John",      1.9);
    list_add(list, 342109, "Rebecca",   6.4);
    list_add(list, 342834, "Shirley",   2.6);
    list_add(list, 343009, "Simon",     1.4);
    list_add(list, 342170, "Antonio",   3.5);

    list_print(list);

    struct node *simon = list_find_by_id(list, 343009);
    struct node *becky = list_find_by_id(list, 342109);

    if (simon && becky) {
        list_swap(list, simon, becky);
        list_print(list);
    }

    list_destroy(list);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this was more than I was expecting! Very helpful.