# swap in doubly linked list

Tags: c, swap, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to swap two nodes in a doubly linked list. Below is the part of program having swap function.

```
 int swap (int x, int y)
{
    struct node *temp = NULL ;
    struct node *ptr1, *ptr2;
    temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));


    if (head == NULL )
    {
        printf("Null Nodes");

    }
    else
    {
        ptr1 = ptr2 = head;

        int count = 1;
        while (count != x)
        {
            ptr1 = ptr1->next;
            count++;

        }



        int count2 = 1;
        while (count2 != y)
        {
            ptr2 = ptr2->next;
            count2++;   

        }       


        ptr1->next->prev = ptr2;
        ptr1->prev->next = ptr2;
        ptr2->next->prev = ptr1;
        ptr2->prev->next = ptr1;

    temp->prev = ptr1->prev;
    ptr1->prev = ptr2->prev;
    ptr2->prev = temp->prev;

    temp->next = ptr1->next;
    ptr1->next = ptr2->next;
    ptr2->next = temp->next;


    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this program, in case of 1st and 2nd node, it crashes. while in case of any other nodes, it gives infinite loop output. (eg:- 2->4 2->4 2->4....so on)`.

I know there are some more questions about node swappings, but I didn't find any one similar to my problem. Please help me out..!!

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: As for the erroring, consider the fact that you never update your `head` pointer. That should be a good start to finding your missed cases.

Comment: But I am using pointers ptr1 & ptr2.(assigned to head) And these are updated in while loop.

Comment: Consider successfully swapping positions 1 and 3 with your function (if it were working). You'd have this `(head) -> (2) -> (3)` -> `(3) -> (2) -> (head)` `ptr` and `head` may point to the same memory location, but they're not the same variable.

Comment: @Sujit: Yes, but these pointers are copies of the `head` that will go out of scope when the `swap` function returns, leaving the original `head` unchanged. (You could maybe make `ptr1` and `ptr2` pointers to pointers to nodes, so that you update the head or the links between nodes via those pointers, though.)

Comment: Also, swapping code does not need to allocate memory (which you don't free in your code). Swapping nodes just means that you rearrange the existing pointers. You may need temporary storage for pointers, but no temporary storage for nodes.

Comment: @MOehm in that case, will it work if I call the display function inside this swap function?

Comment: In which case? Calling the display function from within the swap function is not a good idea, except maybe for debugging purposes. Swapping nodes and printing are two separate actions and hence should be two separate functions.

Comment: [Here's a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368233/is-anything-wrong-with-my-doubly-linked-list-swap-function).

Comment: @MOehm  thats what I wanted to know, how can I swap nodes without using pointers, and if using pointers how the scope can be global.?

Comment: @user3386109 how is that question similar?  Thats c++ and this question is for C

Comment: your code is leaking memory temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

Comment: @Sujit Wow, did you even glance at the accepted answer?

Comment: My thoughts for the crash in case of 1st node is the 1st node's prev pointer would be NULL and has to be retained and not moved to ptr2

Comment: @user3386109 Yes I went through your answer, its really helping. Sorry I was saying about the question. One thing thats disturbing me the most is; how m getting infinite  loop in output?

Comment: @Sujit I think you end up with a node where the `next` pointer points to the same node, e.g. `ptr2->next = ptr2`. When you reach such a node, the output function will loop forever on that node.

Comment: @user3386109 Output is showing two nodes (eg:- 2->4 infinite number of times) . I am not able to figure out where in the code the next pointer points to the same node. can you help me with this?

Comment: @Sujit Why don't you swap the values of nodes?

Comment: @Dante.  Value swapping I've done easily. I want to swap nodes(including pointers),

Comment: @Sujit say u have 2<>3<>4<>5<>6 and x and y are 1 and 3,what is the output?

Comment: I have mentioned already, it crashes whenever I use 1st node.  In your example , if x and y are 2 and 4, output will have 3->5 infinite number of times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code will fail if ptr1 == head (ptr1->prev == NULL) or ptr2 == head (ptr2->prev == NULL), because it ends up trying to use head->next, which doesn't exist. There also needs to be a check for the end of a list, if ptr1->next == NULL or ptr2->next == NULL, which can be handled using a local tail pointer. Using pointers to pointer to node can simplify the code. For example the pointer to next pointer to ptr1 could be &ptr1->prev->next or &head. The pointer to prev pointer to ptr2 could be &ptr2->next->prev or &tail (and set tail = ptr2).

Using pointers to pointer to node fixes the issue with swapping adjacent nodes. Also temp can be a pointer to node.

Example code using pointers to nodes (instead of counts) to swap:

```
typedef struct node NODE;
/* ... */
NODE * SwapNodes(NODE *head, NODE *ptr1, NODE *ptr2)
{
NODE **p1pn;            /* & ptr1->prev->next */
NODE **p1np;            /* & ptr1->next->prev */
NODE **p2pn;            /* & b->prev->next */
NODE **p2np;            /* & b->next->prev */
NODE *tail;             /* only used when x->next == NULL */
NODE *temp;             /* temp */
    if(head == NULL || ptr1 == NULL || ptr2 == NULL || ptr1 == ptr2)
        return head;
    if(head == ptr1)
        p1pn = &head;
    else
        p1pn = &ptr1->prev->next;
    if(head == ptr2)
        p2pn = &head;
    else
        p2pn = &ptr2->prev->next;
    if(ptr1->next == NULL){
        p1np = &tail;
        tail = ptr1;
    } else
        p1np = &ptr1->next->prev;
    if(ptr2->next == NULL){
        p2np = &tail;
        tail = ptr2;
    }else
        p2np = &ptr2->next->prev;
    *p1pn = ptr2;
    *p1np = ptr2;
    *p2pn = ptr1;
    *p2np = ptr1;
    temp = ptr1->prev;
    ptr1->prev = ptr2->prev;
    ptr2->prev = temp;
    temp = ptr1->next;
    ptr1->next = ptr2->next;
    ptr2->next = temp;
    return head;
}
```

Comment: Have tried rearranging the order ... still, the result is same :(

Comment: ptr1->next->prev = ptr2;
  ptr1->prev->next = ptr2;
  ptr2->next->prev = ptr1;
  ptr2->prev->next = ptr1;
  
  temp->prev = ptr1->prev;
  ptr1->prev = ptr2->prev;
  ptr2->prev = temp->prev;
  
  temp->next = ptr1->next;
  ptr1->next = ptr2->next;
  ptr2->next = temp->prev;
  
  temp->data = ptr1->data;
  ptr1->data = ptr2->data;
  ptr2->data = temp->data;

Comment: @Sujit - I updated my answer to show usage of double pointers (pointer to pointer). The issue is that the code overwrites next and prev for adjacent nodes. I don't why you had trouble with non-adjacent nodes. The double pointers don't get overwritten, when you swap between ptr1 and ptr2.

Comment: Thanks. its working for nodes other than head/tail.  I will try adding that exception to it.

Comment: @Sujit - I had to leave before, so I added code showing head / tail handling.

Comment: @Sujit - If the calling code has both a head and tail pointer, the function can be changed to take pointer to pointer for head and tail: void SwapNodes(NODE **phead, NODE **ptail, NODE *ptr1, NODE *ptr2); , updating head and tail if needed within the code and returning void.

Answer (score 0):

This can be compacted, but if you are having problems, it can help to spell it out in detail.

```
typedef struct node Node;

void link( Node* a, Node* b )
{
    a->next = b;
    b->prev = a;
}

void swap_nodes( Node* a, Node* b )
{
    if(a==b) return; // don't swap with yourself

    // handle adjacent nodes separately
    if( a->next == b )
    {
        Node* bef = a->prev;
        Node* aft = b->next;
        link( bef, b);    // link bef, b, a, aft
        link( b, a );
        link( a, aft );
    }
    else if( b->next == a )
    {
        Node* bef = b->prev;
        Node* aft = a->next;
        link( bef, a);   // link bef, a, b, aft
        link( a, b );
        link( b, aft );
    }
    else
    {
        Node* a_prv = a->prev;
        Node* a_nxt = a->next;
        Node* b_prv = b->prev;
        Node* b_nxt = b->next;

        link( a_prv, b ); link( b, a_nxt ); // links b in a's old position
        link( b_prv, a ); link( a, b_nxt ); // links a in b's old position
    }
}
```

Also note that your head node should never be `null`, it should be a sentry node that links to itself if your list is empty. This means that there are never a first node, nor a last, nor is the list ever empty. This removes a ton of special cases. See [here](http://pastebin.com/HC1DLK4M)

Comment: Did you mean "Also _note that your head_ node..."?

Comment: 10 calls for the function link... its very confusing for me.... still I will try in this manner later. Thanks for your time.