# Swapping Doubly linked List

Tags: c, linked-list, swap, doubly-linked-list

I program is getting Stuck. Please Help me:

```
int areTheyNeighbours(struct student_record_node* A,struct student_record_node* B) {
    return ( A->next_ == B && B->prev_ == A ) || ( A->prev_ == B && B->next_ == A );
}
void refreshOuterPointers(struct student_record_node*A) {
    if (A->prev_ != NULL)
        A->prev_->next_ = A;

    if (A->next_ != NULL)
        A->next_->prev_ = A;
}
/*Swap function accpects value from sort function and preforms the actual swap*/
void swap(struct student_record_node** node1, struct student_record_node** node2)
{
/*
  student_record *tmp;

  tmp = (*node1)->record_;
  (*node1)->record_ = (*node2)->record_;
  (*node2)->record_ = tmp;*/


  struct student_record_node* A;
  struct student_record_node* B;
  struct student_record_node* temp;
  struct student_record_node* swapperVector[4];
  A = *node1;
  B = *node2;
  if (A == B)
  {return;}
  if (B->next_=A){
    temp=A;
    A=B;
    B=temp;
  }
   swapperVector[0] = A->prev_;
   swapperVector[1] = B->prev_;
   swapperVector[2] = A->next_;
   swapperVector[3] = B->next_;

   if (areTheyNeighbours(A,B)) {
       A->prev_ = swapperVector[2];
       B->prev_ = swapperVector[0];
       A->next_ = swapperVector[3];
       B->next_ = swapperVector[1];
   } else {
       A->prev_ = swapperVector[1];
       B->prev_ = swapperVector[0];
       A->next_ = swapperVector[3];
       B->next_ = swapperVector[2];
   }

   refreshOuterPointers(A);
   refreshOuterPointers(B);


}
```

I am trying to swap the position of the Nodes, not values. Please help. It's a doubly linked list. I am not sure where I am going wrong. It's for a College Homework. I am newbie please help.

Comment: Hi, please debug your code to know what exactly is wrong. Then ask a specific question here.

Comment: Maybe you should look at [SO 32578455](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32578455).  It too is swapping two nodes in a doubly-linked list.  Issues you need to think about include: Is the list circular? How is the head tracked? Is the tail tracked?  If so, how?  If you swap two items and one of them is the head or the tail of the list, you need to be able to update things appropriately.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39618642/2235885 also uses a side table, but for pointer-to-pointers. (but it is for the special case of the DLL being placed in a container array)