# Is there a general set of instructions to swap adjacent and non-adjacent records in a linked list?`

Tags: singly-linked-list

With a singly linked list, swapping non-adjacent cells can be described by the following operation, assuming '=>' means 'now links to':

```
Y => X->next
X => Y->next
BeforeY => X
BeforeX => Y
```

However, this operation does not work for swapping adjacent records, creating circular links, as X->next (say) will be Y.

Adjacent record swaps, assuming X is before Y, can be described by a separate set of operations:

```
X => Y->next
Y => X
BeforeX => Y
```

I can't seem to solve this set of operations as a subset of the previous set or common children of a parent set.

Is there a uniform, unconditional set of operations that describes a swap that works for both adjacent and non-adjacent records?

Comment: One other special case to at least worry about: one of the swapped nodes was the head of the list.  It might fall out in the wash, or it might lead to you losing access to a significant chunk of the list.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm aware of that one, too, but the sorting algorithm I'm working with accounts for that.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad you have the head of the list covered.  Draw diagrams — pairs of diagrams.  Draw arrows on the diagrams — one member of the pair for before, and one for after.  Then work out what changes.  The X adjacent to Y case (assuming X->next == Y before) has BeforeY == X.  It can be done — you might need temporary variables to hold some pointers (one, at most two).  I've not sat down and finished the thinking.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have 4 pages of such diagrams written down and reviewed with my wife, and we couldn't figure it out.  Only came here after 48 hours of thinking about it.

Comment: OK. You might find [Swap in doubly-linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32578455/swap-in-doubly-linked-list) helpful, or you might not since with a DLL you have a pointer to the previous entry available, but with an SLL you do not and so you need 4 node pointers in general (BeforeX, X, BeforeY, Y) to have access to the data that must be altered. My solution is available in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as file `dllswap.c` in the [src/so-3257-8455](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/so-3257-8455) sub-directory.

Comment: There are comments in the code that may give assistance — at least, a different way of thinking about it (deleting and inserting nodes, instead of swapping per se, but the net result is the same).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The input to my swap function is BeforeX and BeforeY, and I cache the initial data (including AfterX and AfterY) at entry, so that's definitely covered. I'd post source, but it's Forth so I don't expect it to illuminate anything.

Comment: I've not done any serious Forth, really; I looked at it late in the last millennium, but … you're right.  It wouldn't help me.  Yes, BeforeX and BeforeY are sufficient information; you can deduce X and Y from those easily enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some ASCII Art for the two scenarios.

#### Non-adjacent X and Y

X can come before or after Y in the list as long as there is at least one element between X and Y (so Ax and By could identify the same node when X comes before Y).  The situation before:

```
     Bx       X        Ax           By       Y        Ay

   +----+   +----+   +----+       +----+   +----+   +----+   
   |    |   |    |   |    |       |    |   |    |   |    |   
-->|    |-->|    |-->|    |--...->|    |-->|    |-->|    |-->
   |    |   |    |   |    |       |    |   |    |   |    |   
   +----+   +----+   +----+       +----+   +----+   +----+
```

The situation after:

```
     Bx       X        Ax           By       Y        Ay
                   +------------------------------+
                   |                              |
          +------------------------------+        |
          |        |                     |        |
   +----+ | +----+ | +----+       +----+ | +----+ | +----+   
   |    |-+ |    |-+ |    |       |    | +>|    | +>|    |
-->|   @|   |   @|   |    |--...->|   @|   |   @|   |    |-->
   |    | +>|    | +>|    |       |    |-+ |    |-+ |    |
   +----+ | +----+ | +----+       +----+ | +----+ | +----+   
          |        |                     |        |
          +------------------------------+        |
                   |                              |
                   +------------------------------+
```

The 4 'next' pointers marked with `@` are changed.

Before:

```
Bx->next = X
X->next  = Ax
By->next = Y
Y->next  = Ay
```

After:

```
Bx->next = Y
Y->next  = Ax
By->next = X
X->next  = Ay
```

#### Adjacent X and Y

Assume X immediately precedes Y.  The situation before:

```
     Bx         X          Ax
                By         Y          Ay

   +----+     +----+     +----+     +----+
   |    |     |    |     |    |     |    |
-->|    |---->|    |---->|    |---->|    |-->
   |    |     |    |     |    |     |    |
   +----+     +----+     +----+     +----+
```

The situation after:

```
     Bx         X          Ax
                By         Y          Ay
                                   
          +------------+
          |            |
   +----+ |   +----+   | +----+     +----+
   |    |-+   |    |   +>|    |     |    |
-->|   @|     |   @|     |   @|     |    |-->
   |    |   +>|    |-+   |    |-+ +>|    |
   +----+   | +----+ |   +----+ | | +----+
            |        |          | |
            +-------------------+ |
                     |            |
                     +------------+
```

Before:

```
Bx->next = X
X->next  = Ax = Y
By->next = Y
Y->next  = Ay
```

After:

```
Bx->next = Y
Y->next  = X        # Different
By->next = Ay       # Different
X->next  = Ay
```

The result values in the pointers are different, as shown.  This means that there isn't a single mapping that works for both the "non-adjacent X and Y" and the "adjacent X and Y" cases — the pointer twizzling must be different.

Comment: Was hoping that I was missing something, but thanks for verifying that there is no common set.