# Swapping structs by value (array of pointers)

Tags: c, struct

I have this struct (doubly linked list with info represented as an array of 37 pointers):

```
typedef struct list {
    struct list* next;
    struct list* prev;
    char *arr[37];
} List;
```

And I must swap any two elements. I tried swapping them by pointers, but I couldn't really find a solution (so if you can help me with that I would be glad). 
So I came up with this solution I feared from the start:

```
void swap_values(List *p1, List *p2) {
    char **temparr = malloc(37 * sizeof(char*));
    for (int i = 0; i < 37; i++) {
        *(temparr + i) = malloc(sizeof(p1 -> arr[i]));
        strcpy(temparr[i], p1 -> arr[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 37; i++) {
        strcpy(p1 -> arr[i], p2 -> arr[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 37; i++) {
        strcpy(p2 -> arr[i], temparr[i]);
        free(*(temparr + i));
    }
    free(temparr);
}
```

Is this proper way of swapping their contents? It doesn't feel right. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code should not be using `strcpy`. For each `i`, just swap the two pointers. There's also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368233) which discusses how to swap elements of a doubly linked list.

Comment: @user3386109 thanks, I did it, but how do I free the excess memory? If I'm correct, I used malloc 3 times, for p1, p2 and for temporary array. I should be able to free one array am I right?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `malloc` at all. The code should be swapping one pointer at a time. So there should be a `temp` variable declared as `char *temp;`

Answer (score 0):

> Is this proper way of swapping their contents?

If you want to swap the data part (and keep the next/prev pointers untouched) all you need is:

```
void swap_values(List *p1, List *p2) 
{
    char* tmp;
    for (int i = 0; i < 37; i++) 
    {
        tmp = p1->arr[i];
        p1->arr[i] = p2->arr[i];
        p2->arr[i] = tmp;
    } 
}
```

An alternative approach could be:

```
void swap_values(List *p1, List *p2) 
{
    char *tmp[37];
    memcpy(tmp, p1->arr, 37 * sizeof(char*));
    memcpy(p1->arr, p2->arr, 37 * sizeof(char*));
    memcpy(p2->arr, tmp, 37 * sizeof(char*));
}
```

If you want to swap the nodes (instead of the data inside), you'll need another function prototype. This is because the nodes being swapped may be the first and/or the last nodes. In that case, the `head` and/or `tail` pointers will change.

Probably something like:

```
void swap_values(List *p1, List *p2, List **head, List **tail){ ... }
```

Comment: There's no need to swap the memory around, since the entire point of linked lists is to move the pointers around (cheap) to avoid moving memory (expensive).

Comment: @ManicDee OPs question is "Is this proper way of swapping **their contents**?" This is what is answered here. Not whether it's a good idea or not.

Comment: the question originally asks: "And I must swap any two elements. I tried swapping them by pointers, but I couldn't really find a solution …" then veers into the world of swapping contents.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not really clear but I assume your function is receiving pointers to two elements that are members of lists (may or may not be the same list) and you want to have one take the other's place in its list and vice versa .

If so then you can copy the `arr` using memcpy (since arrays cannot be assigned by value) and leave the linking pointers untouched:

```
void swap_values(List *p1, List *p2) 
{
    List temp  = *p1;
    memcpy(&p1->arr, &p2->arr, sizeof p1->arr);
    memcpy(&p2->arr, &temp.arr, sizeof p2->arr);
}
```